# Loop t.test over columns in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, t-test

I have a numeric and several binary variables.
I'd like to loop a ttest for each binary variable.

Using

```
library(boot)
df <- nuclear
```

both

```
  t.test(df$cost, df[6])
```

and

```
  t.test(df$cost, df$pr)
```

give me the same result.
However, If I want to loop it, I'll do the following:

```
for(i in 6:9) {
  t.test(df$cost, df[i])
}
```

which then doesnt give any output.

How can I get a result here and why is this output supressed?

Comment: Take a look at the `*apply` family. If you need a package, I think `rstatix` might have a vectorised t test(I am not sure, never used it but like the dev's work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution using lapply:

```
library(boot)

df <- nuclear 


list_of_ttests <- lapply(6:9, function(i){
    t.test(df[,1], df[,i])
})
```

This generates a list of t-tests and saves them to a list.

Answer (score 1):

If it is just about the missing output, you only need to add `print`.

```
library(boot)
df <- nuclear
for(i in 6:9) {
  print(t.test(df$cost, df[i]))
}
```